# Pandas Dataframe Check if column value is in column list

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, list-comprehension, apply

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
data = {'id':[12,112],
        'idlist':[[1,5,7,12,112],[5,7,12,111,113]]
       }
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

which looks like this:

```
    id                idlist
0   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]
1  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]
```

I need to check and see if `id` is in the `idlist`, and select or flag it.  I have tried variations of the following and receive the commented error:

```
df=df.loc[df.id.isin(df.idlist),:] #TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
df['flag']=df.where(df.idlist.isin(df.idlist),1,0) #TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Some possible other methods to a solution would be `.apply` in a list comprehension?

I am looking for a solution here that either selects the rows where `id` is in `idlist`, or flags the row with a 1 where `id` is in `idlist`.  The resulting `df` should be either:

```
   id              idlist
0  12  [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]
```

or:

```
   flag   id                idlist
0     1   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]
1     0  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x['id'] in x['idlist']), axis=1)
print (df)
    id                idlist  flag
0   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]     1
1  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]     0
```

Similar:

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['idlist'], axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
    id                idlist  flag
0   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]     1
1  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]     0
```

With `list comprehension`:

```
df['flag'] = [int(x[0] in x[1]) for x in df[['id', 'idlist']].values.tolist()]
print (df)
    id                idlist  flag
0   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]     1
1  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]     0
```

---

Solutions for filtering:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['idlist'], axis=1)]
print (df)
   id              idlist
0  12  [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]

df = df[[x[0] in x[1] for x in df[['id', 'idlist']].values.tolist()]]
print (df)

   id              idlist
0  12  [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]
```

Comment: timeits on my df of 1.6m rows:

Comment: I think list comprehension solution should be faster.

Comment: here they are:timeits on my df of 1.6m rows: df['flag'] = df.loc[:, ('id', 'idlist')].apply(lambda x: 1 if x[0] in x[1] else 0, axis=1) 2min10s | df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x['id'] in x['idlist']), axis=1) 1min55s | df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['id'] in x['idlist'], axis=1).astype(int) 1min54s | df['flag'] = [int(x[0] in x[1]) for x in df[['id', 'idlist']].values.tolist()] 1min24s | df.apply(lambda  x : set([x.id]).issubset(x.idlist),1).astype(int).  The various loops below and deleted were much slower.  Winner is the list comprehension version from @jezreal!

Comment: winner is the list comprehension based on my timeits

Answer (score 4):

You can use `df.apply` and process each row and create a new column flag that will check the condition and give you result as second output requested.

```
df['flag'] = df.loc[:, ('id', 'idlist')].apply(lambda x: 1 if x[0] in x[1] else 0, axis=1)

print(df)
```

where `x[0] is id` and `x[1] is idlist`

Comment: you can just use column names for indexing, so: `df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.id in x.idlist, axis=1)`

Comment: @Swier - this is in my answer ;)

Comment: @jezrael dammit, you beat me to it :P

Answer (score 2):

Try simple `for` loop:

```
flaglist = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.id[i] in df.idlist[i]:
        flaglist.append(1)
    else:
        flaglist.append(0)
df["flag"] = flaglist
```

df:

```
    id                idlist  flag
0   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]     1
1  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]     0
```

To drop rows:

```
flaglist = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.id[i] not in df.idlist[i]:
        flaglist.append(i)
df = df.drop(flaglist)
```

df:

```
   id              idlist  flag
0  12  [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]     1
```

Above can be converted to list comprehension for creating a flag column:

```
df["flag"] = [df.id[i] in df.idlist[i]    for i in range(len(df))]
print(df)
#     id                idlist   flag
# 0   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]   True
# 1  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]  False
```

or

```
df["flag"] = [1 if df.id[i] in df.idlist[i] else 0    for i in range(len(df))]
print(df)
#     id                idlist  flag
# 0   12    [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]     1
# 1  112  [5, 7, 12, 111, 113]     0
```

and for selecting out rows:

```
flaglist = [i   for i in range(len(df))   if df.id[i] in df.idlist[i]]
print(df.iloc[flaglist])
#    id              idlist
# 0  12  [1, 5, 7, 12, 112]
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `issubset`

```
df.apply(lambda  x : set([x.id]).issubset(x.idlist),1).astype(int)
Out[378]: 
0    1
1    0
dtype: int32
```

By using `np.vectorize`

```
def myfun(x,y):
    return np.in1d(x,y)


np.vectorize(myfun)(df.id,df.idlist).astype(int)
```

Timing :

```
%timeit np.vectorize(myfun)(df.id,df.idlist).astype(int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.3 µs per loop
%timeit df.apply(lambda  x : set([x.id]).issubset(x.idlist),1).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 353 µs per loop
```

Comment: @clg4 one sec , let me provide another one

Comment: tried the vectorize option, and it was actually much slower than the others on my data set...